# Shuffle string of digits

Tags: code-golf, string

### Challenge

You have been given a string of digits 0-9.<sup>1</sup> Your task is to shuffle this string, but every index must have a different value than it did before the string was shuffled.

For example:

```
In : 287492
Out: 892247
```

If this is not possible, return `false` or something similar. (`null`, `undefined`, etc.)

```
In : 131
Out: false
```

There is no upper bound on the length of the string, but you can assume you have unlimited computation time.

Your function must pass the following tests:

```
shuffle('2')                   => false
shuffle('88')                  => false
shuffle('794588888')           => false
shuffle('344999')              => for example, '999434'
shuffle('172830560542976539')  => for example, '271038650425697395'
```

**Shortest code wins, and good luck!**

---

<sup>1</sup> More specifically, the string would match `/^[0-9]+$/`.

Comment: so, you are asking for derangements...

Comment: Yes, I looked it up and that's what it would be... I'll add it to the description, but I had a question first regarding the details: Would the fact that numbers can appear multiple times in the string affect the derangements? E.g., what I am describing means '111222' can't become '121212', whereas with derangements, could you say, "well, it was a different 2"? (If that makes any sense)

Comment: Does the output have to be randomized? The challenge is tagged random but it doesn't say

Comment: @xnor, no it does not. I just thought to tag it that because it has to do with shuffling. There is no constraint on randomness, and neither do all the options have to be equally likely. It just has to create the outcome described. I'll remove the tag, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Would it be okay to throw an error when the shuffling is not possible (and output nothing to STDOUT)?

Comment: Or alternatively, would we be permitted to output all possible strings that meet the criteria?

Comment: @mathjunkie, both of those things you proposed would be allowed. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/103536/36398)

Comment: @LuisMendo Only difference is that the other challenge asks for a list and this one a string, right? But since strings are allowed to be input as character-lists/arrays by default, isn't it just a dupe? The 7-byte MATL answer in that linked challenge can for example [directly be used as is here](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyHKocTdNvH/f3UjC3MTSyN1AA); most of the other answers will need to have the input in list format to work though.

Comment: @Kevin I’m not sure, because this challenge doesn’t seem to require random output, i.e. it can be deterministic (it’s not clear to me from the challenge specification)

Comment: @LuisMendo Ah, I missed the random part in that other challenge. Yeah, then they are indeed different, but as you already mentioned, very closely related. We could tag Stewie to mention he can post his 7-byter MATL answer here as well. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes :-) ... pity that he doesn't seem to be active anymore, due to the recent SE issues

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Come to think about, the criterion for dupe is that most answers in the other challenge are competitive here. Probably the best way to generate the derangement is to do it randomly, so it would be a dupe after all

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ah, the Pyth answer here doesn't use randomness... Sorry for all the comment noise!

Comment: @LuisMendo also this question asks a falsey output when not possible, in the other question it assumes the input is possible, as for exemple the PHP answer (that I noticed only after having posted mine, but has same approach) will be stuck in an infinite loop. And it's a non negligeable part of the answer's length in mine

Comment: @Kaddath Good point too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Œ!nẠ¥Ƈ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMW8h7sWHFp6rP3/4fbI//@VjE1MLC0tlQA)**

Answer (score 6):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>37</s> 32 bytes

```
{$[|/x=r:x[,/|2 0N#<x]@<<x;0;r]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/Nqloluka/wrbIqiJaR7/GSMHAT9mmItbBxqbC2sC6KLb2f5q6ho6SkZK1koUFkDC3NDG1AAEg29jExNLSEsgwNDeyMDYwNTMwNTGyNDczNbZU0vwPAA)

`{` `}` function with argument `x`

`$[` `;` `;` `]` if-then-else

`<x` "grade" - the sorting permutation for `x`

`<<x` "rankings" - the inverse of the sorting permutation

`2 0N#` split in two halves (or when length is odd - only approximately)

`|` swap the halves

`,/` concatenate

`x[` `]` use as indices in `x`

..`@<<x` use `<<x` as indices in the previous result (`a@b` is alternative syntax for `a[b]`)

`r:` assign to `r` - the potential result

`x=r` boolean list of which elements of `x` are equal to their counterparts in `r`

`|/` or-reduction, i.e. "any?"

Comment: How does it work? Just curious :)

Comment: @applemonkey496 i'll explain a bit later. i'm still looking for ways to shorten it. generally: sort, rotate by the size of the largest group, and unsort.

Comment: i changed the algorithm slightly - now rotation is by half the length of x

Comment: Neat approach.  So is it looping or doing any recursion, or just checking 2 possibilties.  I'm still a little fuzzy even with the explanation.

Comment: @Jonah no, there's no looping or recursion. i'm not good at explanations, is there anything in particular that should be rephrased?

Comment: I think Im just looking for a concise high level explanation of the algorithm itself, without reference to the specifics of the K implementation

Comment: @Jonah to someone familiar with J, i would describe it as "half-tally rotate under sort" :)

Comment: So sort, rotate half the length, then apply inverse of the original sort?  If that’s right that’s quite the trick... how did you arrive at that insight?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108034/discussion-between-ngn-and-jonah).

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

Like the Pyth answer, outputs all possible shuffled strings or digits.

```
œʒø€Ëà_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9vc2FiaWX//8WTypLDuOKCrMOLw6Bf//8yODc0OTI)

### Explanation

```
œ       Permutations of the input
 ʒ      Filter such that:
  ø        Zipping with the original input
   €Ë      And comparing at corresponding indices
     à_    are all unequal.
```

Comment: I think `œ` is permutations, not powerset

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
f.AnVQT.p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P03PMS8sMESv4P9/JWMTE0tLSyUA)

Outputs all possible strings that meet the criteria given in the question. This results in an empty list for the `false` cases.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
-VI#Q.p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XzfMUzlQr@D//2glYyUdBSUTOGGJRMT@yy8oyczPK/6vmwIA)

Takes input as a list of digit-characters. For example:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Output: all possible derangements, with multiplicity for related characters.

- `.p`: Generate all permutations.
- `#`: Filter on
- `I`: Invariant under
- `-V ... Q`: Removing all characters that are at the same position in the input.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 125 bytes

```javascript
e=>[...Array(i=2+e|0)].every(_=>(s=[...q=(--i+'').slice(1)]).some((_,j)=>_==e[j])|s.sort()+''!=[...e].sort()||console.log(q))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBCoMwEEXPUjfOYBOqXZYJeA4JEtKhRKyJiQhC7p7a0t3jvf8ns5tkowubWPyTS6DCpAYpZR@jOcBR13C@oZa8czxgJAWJvn0lEMI1dY0yzc4ytKhP9G8GGK8TkhqJeJg05nTquAGe48vvy/pvcrZ@SX5mOfsXrIglQNV29wof5QM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>83</s> 80 bytes

```python
lambda l:[p for p in permutations(l)if all(map(cmp,l,p))]
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY6xbsMwDER3fcXBk10YGVIXtQ3kA/oNSQfFkVAWlERQ6pCvd6QEKBfycId7lHv5SfG4@9NlZxuuNwtezwKfFAKKEKfhr9hCKeaeB/KwzH2w0m9BRh5lGL6N1xRAxWlJiTMoSNLytr828j2b1scUXaus@pDLjeJqwDjhvD1xW/NapppK0tdeaLV9xRpUsK4QpVjQoTv8JorPN7rXPepQU46z@099VXzOdGXX7Uczz@Z9mpZlMZ/L9DG3eQA)

Goes through all permutation of the string, and keeps the ones that are different to the original string at every index.

Comment: You should be able to drop the `[0]` since outputting all possible strings is now allowed

Comment: Fun fact: my pyth solution translates almost directly to your solution

Comment: @mathjunkie The generation output of the Pyth solution generates *exactly* this solution, byte-for-byte?

Comment: @Λ̸̸ Not quite (eg. `cmp` vs. `n` which would be `!=` in Python). But I imagine the generated code would be quite similar

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>152</s> 141 bytes

```php
$a=count_chars($s=$argn,1);rsort($a);$a[0]*2<=strlen($s)?:die;for($s=$t=str_split($s);$s!=array_diff_assoc($s,$t);)shuffle($t);echo join($t);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5NDsIgGET3nKI2LIqxSe2PLWJ15yXUNKQtgmmA8OHCy4vS2b28mWSstOF0sdKieZQmvWvM3VMn@TlJWcC8H81b@2GU3EGGoV/tbk@YA@N8hjlhmN@Kx7Y89eDdMut/i1yOk5qZMG6d@GgGsIvyUTIMm547xz/DpIQYOIAZ/2KHPWEE5FuIZc4ixEfJyyi9Uggl6jrU0rrpYlBV15RStG/LriqaQ9HUJW0PTUW/xnplNIT8@gM)

A bit lengthy but it's my first approach, will think more about it later

- displays empty string (exits) if impossible (if the most frequent number occurence is more than half of length of the string)
- uses an array approach and shuffles until it finds a proper result

EDIT: fixed an error in string length var attribution (missing brackets) + improved `while` condition for +1 byte

EDIT2: saved 1 byte, since brackets were mandatory for ternary condition, an `if` is now shorter

EDIT3: saved 11 bytes with the help of [this answer by Titus to a closely related question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103554/90841)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 187 bytes

```javascript
e=>{for(b=a=e.slice().sort(),a=+a.join(""),b=+b.reverse().join("");a<=b;){if(k=(a+"").split("").map(a=>+a),b==k.slice().sort((a,e)=>e-a).join("")&&e.every((a,e)=>a!=+k[e]))return a;a++}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc7BbsIwDAbgO0/R9QCxUiKFwqHq3BdBO7idmUK7JkoKEkI8e1lHyzSkSez2y/Zne09HCpU3rlu29p17hz1jcd5ZL0okZBUaU7EAFazvBCSEktTemlbEMSQlylJ5PrIPw8xUz@kVyxzOZidqFCS/Siq4xnRDU32SE4SFpMFj/fuCoIQBC17Sz7r5nNVw4zR16QVlveU3AM/dwbcR5STl5TLrK9sG27Bq7IeItU43cRK5MY0vLBa3FzjCIpIMAPnsgWm9Sif4nZ@md/c/pO9KP83S9TrLshsc89@0vwI)

-8 bytes thanks VFDan

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 179 bytes

```javascript
e=>{for(b=a=e.slice().sort(),a=+a.join``,b=+b.reverse().join``;a<=b;){if(k=(a+"").split``.map(a=>+a),b==k.slice().sort((a,e)=>e-a).join``&&e.every((a,e)=>a!=+k[e]))return a;a++}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc5Ra8IwEAfwdz9F1wfNkRrI6h5Kd/0iIvRazxHbNSHphCF@9k6tFSYM3Nufy/3@lz0dKNTeuH7Z2S0PDgfG4rizXlRIyCq0pmYBKljfC0gIJam9NV1ZJhXKSnk@sA@XjXGa0ztWORzNTjQoSMbx2brW9GWpPskJwkISnC02v7sFJQxY8JKmqvmc1aX9e3qjF5TNmjcAnvsv30WUk5Sn02yobRdsy6q1HyLWOn2Lk8jd0nheLBZw/QBHWESSASCfPTCtX9MJXvPT9O7@h/Rd6adZulplWTbCW/6bDj8)

Comment: You can save 8 bytes by turning all `("")` to `\`\``:
`e=>{for(b=a=e.slice().sort(),a=+a.join\`\`,b=+b.reverse().join\`\`;a<=b;){if(k=(a+"").split\`\`.map(a=>+a),b==k.slice().sort((a,e)=>e-a).join\`\`&&e.every((a,e)=>a!=+k[e]))return a;a++}}`

Comment: Nice, Thank you for trick!!!